# Growing conditions for hydroponics - Vanilla Planfolia and Saffron (Crocus Sativus)

Tags: watering, indoors, sunlight, hydroponic, temperature

Creating an indoor, temperature and humidity controlled hydroponics setup. Wanted advice on whether I can grow the following:

- Vanilla Planfolia
- Saffron (Crocus sativus)

I was also wondering if anybody knew the optimal conditions to grow these plants. I would need the  following info:

- Humidity
- Temperature
- Watering information (I'll be using a drip system)
- Lighting (I will be using LED solar lights (Red and Blue))

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

They will need different conditions.

Vanilla is a tropical vine and a shade tolerant plant.  An orchid.

Saffron Crocuses, full sunlight, not as much moisture, may require a wider range of conditions.  Being a bulb crop they may need a dormant period.

So these two could not be grown in the same space.